# CSS issue with Table with images - Screenshots included

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm working on a project where I've made my phpmyadmin database spit out a set of 6 images on my webpage. I've put it into a table and this is where the trouble begins - even though it sounds easy!

I need the images to be in three's, in a horizontal line.

I will have 6 images most of the time so 3 per row with good spacing/padding etc.

I've tried a lot of things and played around with the CSS but couldn't get it to work.

Here are (respectively) the actual page and how it looks, the CSS for it and the actual code/script of the table:

Actual Page

[image]

CSS for the table: `table.Evidence td {
                        padding:0px,10px,0px,0px;
                                      }`

Script for the table:

[image]

It looks very easy but I couldn't make it work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm new so please bear with me until I get used to this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: copy and paste your code, so we can use it to debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<tr></tr>` tags should be after every third image, so the if in your while should be:

```
if($i % 3 == 0){
echo "</tr></tr>";
}
else{
echo "<td><img something...></td>";
}
```

Also you must have one `<tr>` opening tag directly after the `<table>` tag, and one `</tr>` closing tag directly before the `</table>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that if you define all 4 paddings in one command you have to seperate them with spaces.

```
table.Evidence td { padding:0px 10px 0px 0px; }
```

It also seems that you don't use the table tags right.
With an `tr` you are adding tan new row and with an `td` you are adding a new cell.

A table of 2x2 cells would look like:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          3
        </td>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Table rendered]